# How to handle data offline Sync with AWS AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, offline, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-ios

I have set up an IOS app with DataSource as "HTTP endpoint". 
I can fetch all users and auto store in mysqli DB and this data is available offline. 
I have also tried the subscriptions to mutations which also works fine.

Now my question is how do I sync the data. suppose I have 10 rows and there is 2 new row available when I was offline. how do I know these are available?

Answer (score 0):

There's an AppSync capability called Delta Sync. You can take a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-delta-sync.html)

Comment: Delta sync works even when app is closed and network available on phone ?  OR it works after app is opened again.